# Teams user profile uninstall via script

Tags: batch-file, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to create a script to populate the existing users folders on a Windows workstation and then do a 'for each' to:
remove the directories
`c:\users\%username%\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\teams`
and also
`c:\users\%username%\appdata\local\Microsoft\teams`
in order to completely gut the system of any left over Teams installs.

I already have the script to install computer-wide Teams, plus a PowerShell script to initiate a Teams install for the user as a scheduled task that triggers immediately, (although teams won't work until a reboot for some reason), but I digress.

Currently I only have the removal script for the logged on user, (although it says it cant find the file), but I know this can be done for all users.

```bash
ECHO Ensure you are running this while logged on to the account of the user that has issues
ECHO Changing to users AppData folder
CD "%AppData%"
ECHO Removing corrupted Teams Files from User account
DEL /S /Q /F "%appdata%\roaming\microsoft\teams\*.*"
DEL /S /Q /F "%appdata%\roaming\microsoft\teams\blob_storage\*.*"
DEL /S /Q /F "%appdata%\roaming\microsoft\teams\cache\*.*"
DEL /S /Q /F "%appdata%\roaming\microsoft\teams\databases\*.*"
DEL /S /Q /F "%appdata%\roaming\microsoft\teams\gpucache\*.*"
DEL /S /Q /F "%appdata%\roaming\microsoft\teams\indexeddb\*.*"
DEL /S /Q /F "%appdata%\roaming\microsoft\teams\Local Storage\*.*"
DEL /S /Q /F  "%appdata%\roaming\microsoft\teams\tmp\*.*"
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "for" loop in Windows command prompt (cmd.exe) to iterate through all the user folders in the "c:\users" directory, and then use the "rd" command (short for "remove directory") to delete the specified folders.

For example, the script could look like this:

```
for /d %i in (c:\users\*) do (
    rd /s /q "c:\users\%i\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\teams"
    rd /s /q "c:\users\%i\appdata\local\Microsoft\teams"
)
```

The /s switch is used to remove all subfolders and files. /q switch is used to delete files without a prompt confirmation.

Please be aware that, this will delete all files and folders inside the specified directory, including all subdirectories and files, so please be sure you are using the correct directory path before running the script.

remember to have a backup of the entire system before making any changes.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do, thank you so much Baljeetsingh Sucharia

Comment: @JoshuaC.Rucker glad it helped you. it would be great if you could upvote this helps to confirm the solution and they get the desired help quickly.

Comment: I wish I could, but since I just started on stackoverflow I only have a reputation of 13 and a minimum of 15 is needed to upvote.

Answer (score -1):

Teams machine wide install:

```
:: install.bat
:: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/hzektt/comment/fzje31l/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3
:: machine wide install, ends up being 32-bit

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Citrix\PortICA /f 
start /wait msiexec /i Teams_windows_x64.msi /qb ALLUSER=1
set err=%errorlevel%

del "c:\users\public\desktop\Microsoft Teams.lnk"

reg delete hklm\software\wow6432node\microsoft\windows\currentversion\run /f /v teams

exit /b %err%
```

Comment: Thanks for that js2010, but it wasn't quite what I was looking for.  What you posted is very similart to another part of my script not in this question... I was more focused on removing the individual teams installs / files for each user when running the command as admin while logged on as a device admin so I could avoid manual removal of these files for all existing user profile folders.

Comment: I would change the title to "Teams user profile uninstall".